# Could not open file v_YoYo_g07_c04.jpeg av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error

Tags: ffmpeg, python-3.5

the purpose of the following code is to extract frames from a list of videos.
To do so l defined in python 3.5 **extract_frames function** which calls **extract_frame function**. In this latter a **ffmpeg** instruction is given to extract the frames

```
def extract_frames(vidlist,vidDir,outputDir):
    f = open(vidlist, 'r')
    vids = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    vids = [video.rstrip() for video in vids]
    for vid in vids:
        videoName = os.path.join(vidDir,vid.split('.')[0]+".avi")
        frameName = os.path.join(outputDir, vid.split('.')[0]+".jpeg")
        extract_frame(videoName,frameName)
extract_frames(trainlist01, ucf101_path,training_output)
```

such that:

```
ucf101_path = "/local/common-data/UCF/UCF-101" # Path to the root dataset
trainlist01="/local/common-data/UCF/ucfTrainTestlist/trainlist01.txt"
training_output = '/local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/'
```

where **trainlist01.txt** contains a set of lines as follow (first column the path to the video and the second is the class of the video) :

**ApplyEyeMakeup/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01.avi 1** .....

And **videoname** and **framename** correspond for instance to :

```
videoname="/local/common-data/UCF/UCF-101/YoYo/v_YoYo_g07_c04.avi"
framename="/local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/test/YoYo/v_YoYo_g07_c04.jpeg"
```

The error is returned by the following function

```
import subprocess

    def extract_frame(videoName,frameName):

        if not os.path.exists(videoName):
            print('%s does not exist!' % videoName)
            return False
        # call ffmpeg and grab its stderr output
        p = subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i %s -r 1 -s qvga -t 1 -f image2 %s' % (videoName,frameName), shell=True)
        return p
```

The error is  : 
**[image2 @ 0x422ff80] Could not open file : /local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/YoYo/v_YoYo_g25_c05.jpeg
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error**

and the output files **training_output** where l supposed to get my frames is empty.

files and folders ad subfolders have all right .

What's wrong with my code ?

**EDIT 1**

After creating a subfolder YoYo/ in /local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/ and run again the code l got this new error :

```
Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '/local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/YoYo/v_YoYo_g25_c05‌​.jpeg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern) av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Comment: 1. Check that `/local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/YoYo/` is correct and exists. 2. Ensure that you have the proper permissions to write to the directory.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard. l just checked for the permission and l have all the permissions. YoYo/ effectively doesn't exit (it's supposed to be created by the code automatically when there is a new folder, l check later on for that). When l l created YoYo/ folder and run again the code l got the following error :      Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '/local/common-data/UCF/tmp_frames/train/YoYo/v_YoYo_g25_c05.jpeg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed with the following command :

```
p = subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i %s  -vf scale=224:-1 %s' % (videoName,frameName), shell=True)
```